# What password one-way hash should I use in PHP when bcrypt is unavailable?

Tags: php, bcrypt

I have to deploy a php app for a client, but his server doesn't support bcrypt. I have no way to change this. What should I use instead of bcrypt to hash the user's passwords?

Comment: do you really need 2 way password, did you tried with one way hashing like sha?

Comment: `SHA-512` and couple thousands rounds?

Comment: @Hawili: where did you get about 2-way?

Comment: As @zerkms said, I don't want two-way. Looking into SHA, if that's what everyone seems to think the most secure (easily implemented) alternative is.

Comment: @zerkms oops I read bcrypt but thought about blowfish! I should quit smoking ;) , anyway , you can always check [http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) they have some pure php implementations that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**bcrypt** is ideal for password hashing because it is slow, in addition to other useful properties.

Using SHA256, or even SHA1 with an appropriate salted value should do the job quite well for most password-hashing-purposes.

--

See also: http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: To get `sha` slow as well you still need to do that more than once for the password